# Não compreendo uma sintaxe que não há vírgula após a declaração de uma função dentro de um array

Tags: javascript

A parte em negrito, porque não há uma virgula entre os parênteses, não achei referência sobre essa escrita.

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-uncss"**)(**{
            html: [
                './index.html'
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: É importante lembrar, apesar de funcionar, isso provavelmente não é uma boa ideia, em muitas linguagens a importação de outros arquivos é feita sempre no início do arquivo, mesmo as que não é obrigatório também fazem isso, é um padrão adotado por todos, pra não usar esse padrão, deve-se ter um motivo. Além disso, essa forma não permite reuso, se em alguma outra parte você quiser usar o módulo, terá que reimporta-lo, ou usar o padrão de no início do arquivo salvar o módulo numa variável, e, se isso for feito, pode deixar o código bagunçado importando apenas uns módulos no início e os outros não

Answer (score 2):

Não há uma virgula porque isso tudo é apenas um valor. O que está acontecendo aí não é a declaração de uma função, é a chamada de uma função.

Isso:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-uncss")({
            html: [
                './index.html'
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```

É o equivalente a isso:

```
const postcssUncss = require("postcss-uncss");
const postcssPlugin = postcssUncss({ html: ['./index.html'] });

module.exports = {
    plugins: [postcssPlugin]
}
```

Você está importando o módulo `postcss-uncss`, que está expondo uma função, e imediatamente você invoca a função passando o parâmetro `{ html: ['./index.html'] }`. O retorno dela é o valor passado para o *array* `plugins`.

Comment: A chamada da require ali no caso tá retornando uma função anônima e sendo imediatamente invocada? Tem um nome técnico para isso ou artigo?

Comment: A função não é necessariamente anônima, ela é uma função que foi exportada pelo módulo que você importou, se ela foi declarada com um nome ou de forma anônima é irrelevante. Não acho que exista um nome específico para esse estilo. Quando você declara e invoca uma função imediatamente, isso é chamado `IIFE`, mas nunca vi ninguém se referir ao ato de importar e invocar uma função como `IIFE`.

Comment: Eu acho que vi algo assim no pouco de programação funcional que vi, acho que se chama currying, não estava me lembrando, mas não posso confirmar.